# Get SerializedName param from child class in Kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin, gson

I am trying to parse an API response mainly constructured like this:

```
{
    "ApiFunc1":{
        "SomeData1":"SomeValue1",
        "SomeData2":"SomeValue2",
        "SomeData3":"SomeValue3"
    }
}


{
    "ApiFunc2":{
        "SomeData4":"SomeValue4",
        "SomeData5":"SomeValue5",
        "SomeData6":"SomeValue6"
    }
}
.
.
.
```

I created a base class as follows:

```
class Model_BaseResponse<TResponse> : Serializable {

    @SerializedName("ErrorMessage")
    var errorMessage: String? = null

    @SerializedName("value")
    var data: TResponse? = null

}
```

Each ApiFunc returns different data. I want to create a base class where `data: TResponse`'s @SerializedName("ApiFunc1") or @SerializedName("ApiFunc2") can be set in child class. Is there any way to that? I do it in regular way, defining the

```
@SerializedName("value")
var data: TResponse? = null
```

in every child class. Just been curious about that. Thanks in advance for any idea.

Answer (score 1):

An annotation like `SerializedData` requires its arguments to be compile-time constants. Having a look at what "compile-time constant" means in Kotlin reveals:

> Properties the value of which is known at compile time can be marked as compile time constants using the const modifier. Such properties need to fulfil the following requirements:
>
> - Top-level or member of an object
> - Initialized with a value of type String or a primitive type
> - No custom getter
>
> Such properties can be used in annotations:
>
> ```
> const val SUBSYSTEM_DEPRECATED: String = "This subsystem is deprecated"
>
> @Deprecated(SUBSYSTEM_DEPRECATED) fun foo() { ... }
> ```

I believe the first requirement "Top-level or member of an object" cannot be fulfilled for your use case.